Store/load Scikit Learn objects (Pipeline, ColumnTransformer) without different version considerations?
I need to be able to somehow store and reload a Scikit Learn pipeline in a way that breaking changes between different Scikit Learn versions aren't as much of a concern as they are when I use e.g. Pickle or Joblib.
In particular I need to store a ColumnTransformer, OneHotEncoder, some custom transformers and other objects from the pipeline in a way that I can reconstruct them in another area of my setup.
Pickle is out of the question because it relies on a stable API of the stored object. For example I cannot load a ColumnTransformer with its hierarchy in a Python program using Scikit Learn v1.5.1 when the original ColumnTransformer was created using Scikit Learn 1.1.2. It's simply incompatible and I can't even hook into the loading process and manually fix the incompatibilities and breaking changes (e.g. the signature of the OneHotEncoder constructor).
So what can I do to achieve this? I want to avoid retraining everything, rather implement "converters" and use defaults for the breaking changes.
